# First reference to equation underlined

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, equations

In these days I'm writing at my Bachelor's Thesis and I've got a new problem. I have to underline the first reference to figures, tables and equations. By searching in the Internet I've already found a solution for the figures an the tables. But I didn't succeed editing the code, so that is would work with equations. Does anybody know, how to change the solution of figures/tables for the equations? I'm using the align-environment for the equations, labeling it with the prefix `eqn:` (`\ref{eqn:abc}`)

My Code-Sample:

```
\documentclass[
    pagesize,
    DIV = calc,
    liststotoc,
    bibtotoc,
    idxtotoc]{scrreprt}

    \usepackage{amsmath}


\newif\ifMeinFormat
%\MeinFormattrue
\MeinFormatfalse

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\evtlfett{%
\ifMeinFormat
\let\evtlfett\@firstofone
\else
\let\evtlfett\underline
\fi
}%

\def\p@figure{\expandafter\p@@figure}%
\def\p@@figure#1{\@figmkdef{#1}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\@figmkdef[1]{%
\@ifundefined{figmk#1}
{%
\global\@namedef{figmk#1}{}%
\evtlfett{Abbildung #1}%
}%
{Abbildung #1}%
}%

\def\p@table{\expandafter\p@@table}%
\def\p@@table#1{\@tablemkdef{#1}}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\@tablemkdef[1]{%
\@ifundefined{tblmk#1}
{%
\global\@namedef{tblmk#1}{}%
\evtlfett{Tabelle #1}%
}%
{Tabelle #1}%
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{test}
{\begingroup erster Verweis auf die Figur: \ref{fig} \endgroup}\\
zweiter Verweis auf die Figur: \ref{fig}\\
erster Verweis auf die Table: \ref{tab}\\
zweiter Verweis auf die Table: \ref{tab}\\
erster Verweis auf die Gleichung: \ref{eqn:abc}\\
zweiter Verweis auf die Gleichung: \ref{eqn:abc}\\

\begin{figure}
Irgend ne Figur
\caption{\label{fig}Text}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
Irgend ne Table
\caption{\label{tab}Text}
\end{table}

\begin{align}
a + b = c \label{eqn:abc}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good lord, who develops such strange requirements?! The professor should be forced to do this stuff himself only once...

Comment: He does this crap in his own stuff too, but using Word. One of the PhD students asked me, if I could dispose them my tex-template for the students. But I don't know yet ;-)

Comment: How about hooking into `\eqref`, and always using that?

Comment: Can you (or some wizard reading this) hack the figure or table environment so that it doesn't float, but so that you can still take advantage of the solution you have for those? Then put your equations in the new environment. Positioning the equation number might be a problem.

Comment: I already tried to edit the section beginning with \def\p@table, but I don't know, what to write instead of tblmk and so on for the equation-area. The align-enviroment does exactly what I want, it's just the reference.

Comment: If there would be easy wayy to do things like this in common wordprocessors it would be okay I guess. But Word for sure requires manual work and TeX also seems to require a few tricks, since noone had an answer yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

With added improvements, suggested by `egreg` it is now:

```
\documentclass[
    pagesize,
    DIV = calc,
    liststotoc,
    bibtotoc,
    idxtotoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\oldcref\cref% 
  \renewcommand{\cref}[1]{% 
  \ifcsname[#1]\endcsname\relax%
  {\oldcref{#1}}%
  \else%
  {\underline{\oldcref{#1}}%
  }%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname[#1]\endcsname{1}%
  \fi%
  }% 
}

\begin{document}
\section{test}
erster Verweis auf die Figur: \cref{fig} \\
zweiter Verweis auf die Figur: \cref{fig}\\
erster Verweis auf die Table: \cref{tab}\\
zweiter Verweis auf die Table: \cref{tab}\\
erster Verweis auf die Gleichung: \cref{eqn:abc} \\
zweiter Verweis auf die Gleichung: \cref{eqn:abc}\\
dritte Verweis auf die Gleichung:  \cref{eqn:abc}\\


\begin{figure}
Irgend ne Figur
\caption{\label{fig}Text}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
Irgend ne Table
\caption{\label{tab}Text}
\end{table}

\begin{align}
a + b = c \label{eqn:abc}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, the underlining is also done by the command \evtlfett in the macro above. In your solution there is only the number underlined. I also need the "Abbildung", "Tabelle" or "Gleichung" underlined. So the best way would be to change this part: 

\def\p@table{\expandafter\p@@table}%

\def\p@@table#1{\@tablemkdef{#1}}%

\DeclareRobustCommand\@tablemkdef[1]{%

\@ifundefined{tblmk#1}

{%

\global\@namedef{tblmk#1}{}%

\evtlfett{Tabelle #1}%

}%

{Tabelle #1}%

}%

Comment: I'd use `\expandafter\gdef\csname[#1]\endcsname` to take care of the case the reference happens to be in a group. For underlining also the name, probably `cleveref` is a good candidate.

Comment: If you use `\cref` instead of `\ref` loading `\usepackage[ngerman]{cleverer}` you get what's desired (which is horrible and completely useless).

Comment: Is it possible that you give a little example so that I get the correct order of the commands? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mafp: now I saw it! I missed the update!